# "the more you help people out , the more you will be happy "

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Is my sentence structure correct for this sentence.. 
and can I say this sentence in different way but imply the same or similar meaning..

> The more you help people out , the more you will be happy
>
> How much you help people out without expecting in return to you, that
>   much you will be happy

:)

Comment: The more you help people, the happier you will be. 

The more you help people, without expecting anything in return, the happier you will be.

Comment: Well another question has just sparked in my mind related to this kind of construction that is it correct to say that  " the more I am getting to know her , the more I want to spend time with her  "  or " the more I get to know humans, the more I love animals "

Comment: 1 is ok, but more conventionally, *The better I know her, the more time I want to spend with her.* 2 is also fine. A more formal way: *The better I know humans, the more I love animals.* Sometimes the informal language is better, stronger: *The more I know people, the more I love animals.*

Comment: Thanks again and I would like to extend the question little bit more in sense that "we can't get enough of something" ..I mean like for example I have eaten an exotic food very first time and I liked it a lot and I say " Oh my god ..it is so tasty that the more I eat the more I would like to eat " ,maybe in a bit childish or figurative or maybe cheeky sense..can we say that sentence in this meaning? is it common?

Comment: I think these are interesting questions about this type of construction that you might include in your original question so that we could re-open it.